# performing operation on views

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a `view T3` as :

```
cliid     fullname   MgrName    Mgrid
  12          V1         Vas       1
  13          V2         xyz       2
  14          V3         abc       4
  15          V4         Vas       1
  16          V5         Vas       1
```

and another `view as T4` :

```
 AckNo     clifullname   
  1222          V1         
  1333          V2        
  2334          V3         
  1533          V4         
  1600          V5
```

I want to perform join on these views to produce result like this :

```
 AckNo      cliid     fullname   MgrName    Mgrid
  1222        12          V1         Vas       1
  1333        13          V2         xyz       2
  2334        14          V3         abc       4
  1533        15          V4         Vas       1
  1600        16          V5         Vas       1
```

I have tried following query so far but getting repeated records I want solution for that.

```
  select T4.AckNo,T3.cliid,T3.FullName,T3.MgrName,T3.MgrId
  from T3
  join T4 On T4.cliFullName=T3.FullName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  select AckNo,cliid,fullname,MgrName,Mgrid from
  (
  select *,rn=ROW_NUMBER()over(order by cliid) from T3 --your view
  )x,
  (
  select *,rn1=ROW_NUMBER()over(order by AckNo) from T4 --your view
  )y
 where x.rn=y.rn1
```

## <kbd>[SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17624)</kbd>

//you could create view like this

```
 create view tiger as
 select AckNo,cliid,fullname,MgrName,Mgrid from
  (
  select *,rn=ROW_NUMBER()over(order by cliid) from tabl1 --your view(T3)
  )x,
  (
  select *,rn1=ROW_NUMBER()over(order by AckNo) from table2 --your view(T4)
  )y
 where x.rn=y.rn1

 select * from tiger
```